# php extension 'interbase' is not loaded

Tags: php, centos7, firebird2.5, interbase, opcache

I searched a lot from the internet but did not find a solution.
I want to define interbase/Firebird in php. (extention) to connect to firebird servers.
but php extension 'interbase' is not loaded.
How can I do that?

thank you so much.

Operating System : Centos 7
Php : Php 5.6.40
Apache  : httpd-2.4.6-90.el7.centos.x86_64

```py
[root@server ~]# yum list installed | grep php
cwp-suphp.x86_64                    0.7.2-3                            @cwp
cwpphp.x86_64                       7.0.32-1                           @cwp
php.x86_64                          5.4.16-46.el7                      @base
php-cli.x86_64                      5.4.16-46.el7                      @base
php-common.x86_64                   5.4.16-46.el7                      @base
php-interbase.x86_64                5.4.16-9.el7                       @epel
php-pdo.x86_64
```

looks loaded

```py
[root@server ~]# ls /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/
opcache.a  opcache.so
```

but not here

Answer (score 0):

You have to install fbclient 2.5, that's expected.

Pdo_firebird loads just fine, PDO is builtin in PHP, there is no need to enable 
php_pdo.dll. Are you sure that you did not mix versions?

---

Try installing a php version 7.0 or 7.1, 7.2
and its modules ...

I don't know if it's available in version 5.4 this extension for Fireburd

Comment: phpinfo() also does not appear.

Comment: did you upgrade and install as described?
Not sure, but I don't think I get information about a module exactly for Facebook.

Tell me what the terminal responds to when you made these installs ...
Was there an error?

could it be positive for instructions that were approved and used by previous users?

Answer (score 0):

Access the terminal (as root) and execute the commands below, according to your system version:

CentOS / RHEL 7.x:

```
    rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpmrpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

CentOS / RHEL 6.x:

```
 rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Installing php 5.6:

```
 yum install php56w php56w-cli php56w-common php56w-devel php56w-mbstring php56w-pecl-imagick php56w-xml
```

Enabling php extensions:

Firebird / Interbase:

```
yum install php56w-interbase
```

Ldap Module:

```
 yum install php56w-ldap
```

GD Module:

```
  yum install php56w-gd
```

MySQL:

```
   yum install php56w-mysql php56w-mysqlnd
```

MSSQL Server:

```
  yum install php56w-mssql
```

ODBC:

```
  yum install php56w-odbc
```

RFQ:

```
 yum install php56w-pdo
```

PostgreSQL:

```
 yum install php56w-pgsql
```

Restart apache:

```
  service httpd restart
```

---

See that you have a module for Firebird in php 5.6

I advise if you have opportunity upgrade to php 7.0 or 7.1 or 7.2

For 5.6 is already on its way to being discontinued.

Send us news about your success, ok ...
Greetings!